# Why does human hair grow and behave differently depending on its location?

Tags: human-biology

Why does human hair behave differently depending on its location? For instance, head hair grows to an indefinite length, but eyebrows maintain a particular length and appearance. Head hair and eyebrows may exhibit balding, but not ear, arm, nose, and facial hair (etc). Why is this so?

Comment: The answer for why is in [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27528/why-does-hair-grow-after-trimming-but-remains-at-a-constant-length-after-a-while/27529#27529) post: basically because of differences in follicle cycling. Are you asking how exactly is this controlled?

Comment: Thank you for the link. And, yes, I am asking how this is controlled.