# What causes head hair to be different than body and face hair?

Tags: human-biology

If you feel your head hair, it typically feels a lot softer and is easier to manage (comb, brush, fix) than a lot of other hair on your body - specifically I'm thinking about beard hair and pubic hair, which typically are a lot coarser than the hair on your head.

Why are these hairs thicker?

What causes them to grow differently than the hair on our head?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27528/why-does-hair-grow-after-trimming-but-remains-at-a-constant-length-after-a-while/27529#27529) post.

Comment: I have previously looked at that post @WYSIWYG, but I don't understand what makes the hair coarse on the body but fine on the head.

Comment: Is it so?? I don't think that is true.

Comment: Well, pull out a piece of hair from your head, and pull out a pubic or beard hair and compare them, the beard and pubic hair are thicker. Also, if you look at hair closely under a microscope, scientists can tell if it is a "head hair" or a "body hair" @WYSIWYG

Comment: Yes, of course body hair is different from head hair based on texture and thickness but I just said that the former may not be necessarily "coarser". It also varies from person to person.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Hair coverings are affected by follicle structure,and eyelashes and eyebrows and so on are also different. An evolutionary reason why these hairs would be different is one thing, and a complete description of all the weird follicles on your body is another.

Comment: A little of both, but more the description of the follicle. Although why it got there in evolution would be interesting to know, too. @Resonating