# What is the structural/chemical difference leading to different shapes in facial/head/pubic hair?

Tags: human-biology, human-genetics, human-physiology, hair

Different hairs have different shapes, thicknesses, properties.

What exactly is different between these types of hairs? a [previous post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27528/why-does-hair-grow-after-trimming-but-remains-at-a-constant-length-after-a-while/27529#27529) implies that the *root* of the differing length (pun intended) is the rate at which the skin sheds the hair. However, this doesn't explain the different degrees of curliness, thicknesses, and textures.

Answer (score 1):

hair shape texture is really easy. the biggest effect is the shape, size, and angle of the hair follicle. Hair with different cross sections have different properties. If hair is stiffer in one plane than other it will tend to bend along the weaker plane. Larger follicles will of course produce thicker, thus stiffer hair and the angle of the follicle can influence the hairs cross sections as mush as the follicles cross sectional shape can. Note the chart below is simplified triangular and kidney shaped cross sections also exist.

[image]

Comment: This is a nice picture, where did you find it?

Comment: Out of one of my lessons, let me see if I can find the original source. here it came from this forensics slide show. https://www.slideshare.net/leahmorgan/forensics-ch-5-6-notes

Comment: At one time I donated a "pinch" of head hair some years ago. A crossection was made with a microtome. The point being that there were many more colors that the photo above; white,black,red, and a dozen shades of tan/brown. My hair was nominally light brown. ( a much better photo also).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the differences between curly and straight hair, different hairs have different hair follicles.

Sex hormones at the onset of puberty rebuild the local [vellus hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vellus_hair) into [terminal hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_hair), which tends to be longer, thicker, and darker. The anagen/telogen/catagen cycle is different for these follicles and as a result they get longer.

Comment: you really should go into what differences their are in follicles.

Comment: As far as I can tell terminal follicles are just bigger?